# Disable Sentry.io during maven install

Tags: java, spring, sentry

I have a Spring Boot application in Java which uses Sentry.io for reporting and capturing exceptions.
What I want to do is to disable Sentry captures when I create a build through maven, for example mvn clean install.
The reason for this is that during testing and debugging, I don't want to get those Sentry captures all the time.

I looked up the Sentry documentation and I found that you can define different environments for Sentry, but I was not able to figure out how to use this for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define this config in `applicaiton-test.yml` (or `.properties`)

```
sentry:
    dsn: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who came there, here is what worked for me :
If you are using Springboot you can use a specific application.properties in your src/test/resources and simply don't set sentry dns property in it.

Now when I run mvn:test issues are not send to Sentry.